# Use docker environment path variable in bash script

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker file to run a machine learning algorithm with parameters given in config.json file. Simplified version of my docker command looks like this

```
docker run --rm -it \
        -e "CONFIG=work/algorithms/config.json" \
        -e "SRC_TYPE=csv"
        --entrypoint /bin/bash \
        $(DOCKER_REPO)/$(DOCKER_IMAGE):$(DOCKER_VERSION)
```

Andy bash script running python command looks like this.

```
#!/bin/sh
python work/algos/neural_network.py \
--ml_conf "$CONFIG" \
--src_type "$SRC_TYPE" \
--log resources/logs/nn_iris.log
```

When I use the CONFIG variable in the script like this, It does not work. But the SRC_TYPE variable works. Could you please let me know the right way to use environment variables which contain path.

Comment: you can use spaces around the `=`? [doc docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) I suggest `-e "SRC_TYPE=csv" ...`

Comment: I am not using spaces in my original code. I typed spaces when copy pasting here by mistake. I'll edit it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would like to use the `config` inside the running docker container. If so you should use docker `volumes` instead. Please see reference [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag)

for example:
`docker run -v /work/algorithms/config.json:/path/to/target -it <image_name:tag>`